# "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException" while executing Query in Sharepoint app model

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am working with Sharepoint app model. I am using autohosted as an option and trying to debug it. I am getting the client context as

`var clientContext = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost()`

By using this I am trying to create sub site in the host web.

```
public string CreateSubSite(string txtUrl, string template, string title, string description,
                                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContext, Page page, XDocument baseConfiguration,
                                bool isChildSite = false)
    {
        // Resolve the template configuration to be used for chosen template
        XElement templateConfig = GetTemplateConfig(template, baseConfiguration);
        string siteTemplate = SolveUsedTemplate(template, templateConfig);

        // Create web creation configuration
        WebCreationInformation information = new WebCreationInformation();
        information.WebTemplate = siteTemplate;
        information.Description = description;
        information.Title = title;
        information.Url = txtUrl;
        // Currently all english, could be extended to be configurable based on language pack usage
        information.Language = 1033;

        // Load host web and add new web to it.
        var rootWeb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;

       // clientContext.Load(rootWeb);
       // clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        //var newWeb = site.Webs.Add(information);
        var newWeb = rootWeb.Webs.Add(information);

        clientContext.Load(newWeb);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();}
```

This is some part of code only. I am getting exception at `clientContext.ExecuteQuery` sating that

> You do not have permission to perform this action or access this
>   resource

. Can any one give me the solution for this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** To create a subsite, your app needs to have proper permissions set in the AppManifest.xml file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx

I would start by giving the App `FullControl` on the `SiteCollection`.

**2)** For the App Only Policy to work, you need to specify the following attribute to the `AppPermissionRequests` element in your AppManifest.xml file:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <!--Leave all the stuff inside intact-->
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

**3)** Get the AppOnlyAccessToken with the following code. It is tested using an AutoHosted App:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);

            Uri sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

            SharePointContextToken contextToken = TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(contextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);

            string appOnlyAccessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(contextToken.TargetPrincipalName, sharepointUrl.Authority, contextToken.Realm).AccessToken;

            using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), appOnlyAccessToken))
            {
                WebCreationInformation information = new WebCreationInformation();
                information.WebTemplate = "STS#0";

                information.Title = "Test Dev Subsite";
                information.Url = "testdevsubsite";

                // Currently all english, could be extended to be configurable based on language pack usage
                information.Language = 1033;

                // Load host web and add new web to it.
                var rootWeb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;

                var newWeb = rootWeb.Webs.Add(information);

                clientContext.Load(newWeb);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Response.Write(newWeb.Title + " created");

            }
        }
```

See this post for more details:
http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-elevate-user-access.html

Comment: I already given this in appmanifest file. I am having only one user whose is the admin for the developer site.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. It should work.

Comment: Bhava. Thanks for help! Stumbled upon answer and found it was you :P

Comment: Haha! Glad I could help :)

Comment: This resolved my issue as well. But, I am creating a Provider-hosted app running in Office 365. This what I noticed. The very first time you deploy your App to the Office 365 Developer Site, you will get the JS access denied error. To fix it, I set the permission of the scope in the AppManifest.xml file to FullControl. Deploy & ran the App. Didn't accept/deny the trust, I stopped the debugger. Again, I set the permission back to Read. Deploy & ran the App. This time I did not get any JS errors and I accepted App trust.

Answer (score 1):

your trying to create a subsite am i right?

now lets break it down! your account that your using does it have full permission? its needed to make a subsite!

> Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and
>   Document Workspace sites.
>
> Full Control

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx

next thing to go by is, even tho your using a specific account you could be using another account to create the subsite! by that i mean what account is running the current `clientContext` under?

have you tried creating a new client context instead of inheriting the object and see if it fails?

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

WebCreationInformation creation = new WebCreationInformation(); 
creation.Url = "web1"; 
creation.Title = "Hello web1"; 
Web newWeb = context.Web.Webs.Add(creation); 

// Retrieve the new web information. 
context.Load(newWeb, w => w.Title); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 

label1.Text = newWeb.Title;
```

ammend the code above to suit your needs!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx

for app context only:

instead of:

```
var clientContext = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost()
```

you should be doing this instead:

this is the context running under the inherited account who started that context

```
var spcontext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
using (var appClientContext = spcontext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
{

}
```

or

this is creating a new context running under actual user account

```
var spcontext = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url); 
using (var appClientContext = spcontext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
{

}
```

**EDIt**

can you test to see what the current user is running under the context your using?

```
var spcontext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
using (var appClientContext = spcontext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
{
   Web web = appClientContext.Web;
   appClientContext.Load(web);
   appClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   appClientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
   appClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   currentUser = appClientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
}
```

the above will return the current user to the app context its running under!

also have a look at this! its a nice pice of code that is similar to yours! he is updating a list item! but its similar concept! scroll down to **THE PAYOFF – RUNS EITHER AS S2S or ACS!**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/09/24/introducing-sharepointcontext-for-provider-hosted-sharepoint-apps.aspx

more importantly he is talking about weather the app is high trust or not!

**EDIT**

are you sure you have setup the app properly?? as you shouldnt be getting the error message! if the account is admin than they should have enough privlages!

goto the app settings and click on properties, you should see somthing like this:

[image]

click on permissions and set accordingly on site collection and web!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx

Comment: I tried in this way also.. but failed. Same permissions error only it is giving..

Comment: iv updated my answer again, dont know if you spotted it?

Comment: In my Page load i wirtten for spcontext as `spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);`. I declared spContext object globally. What is the `ApplicationContext` in the second piece of code... I am not able to find out in visual studio while writing the code.

Comment: its instead of hardcoding the url its getting the current url, there are other ways of getting it!

Comment: so with what I can replace `ApplicationContext` in my scenario?

Comment: just ammended my answer

Comment: Really Thanks for your efforts. But it is still giving error at `appClientContext.ExecuteQuery();`. Any settings need to be changed? I given full control for SiteCollection in AppManifest file.

Comment: for a replacement of applicationcontext change it to HttpContext

Comment: just updated my answer! i now belive that it has todo with the app permissions itself

Comment: Thanks Ali.. Its a simple thing that i need to give following attribute value to true. `AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"`

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you are required to declare two contexts i.e. one for the appweb and other for the host web. Doing this might help you in fixing this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
hostweburl =
    decodeURIComponent(
        getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl')
);
appweburl =
    decodeURIComponent(
        getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl')
 );

$.getScript(
hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js",
somefunction);

});

function somefunction() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
    /*Whatever you want to do*/
}

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";

for (var j = 0; j < params.length; j = j + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[j].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
        return singleParam[1];
  }
}
```

You can get the appweburl and hostweburl by using query

Comment: I have added some javascript code in my answer which I had tried. You may have a look through that if it help. :)

Comment: I am looking for CSOM model in C#. Is it possible to give solution in C# please..